# How to schedule clamdscan weekly (cron jobs on GKE)?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, clamav

How to schedule "clamdscan" to run weekly on an **GKE**?

I am able to trigger the scan manually, but I am not able to find on a way how to schedule it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at [*CronJobs on GKE*](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs):

- Enable GKE API.
- Ensure you have installed & configured [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
- Set up *gcloud*
- Create CronJob

## cronjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
```

- Apply CronJob

```html
kubectl apply -f filename
```